# Filter K-V in array with Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a **mongodb** data base like this:

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("530d24150fef5d9b065909ca"),
    "name" : "name 1",
    "my_array" : [
        {"key" : "date", "value": 19},
        {"key" : "id", "value": 5}
     ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("530d24150fef5d9b065909ca"),
    "name" : "name 2",
    "my_array" : [
        {"key" : "date", "value": 9},
        {"key" : "id", "value": 11}
     ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("530d24150fef5d9b065909ca"),
    "name" : "name 3",
    "my_array" : [
        {"key" : "date", "value": 10},
        {"key" : "id", "value": 13},
        {"key" : "name", "value": 'test'},
     ]
}
```

I want to make a query which depends on the K-V in my_array. I know to list the items have the key-name:

```js
db.test.find({"my_array.key": 'name'})
```

But, I don't know how to filter the items with the key-value, Like get the item which key is 'id' and value bigger than 10. I this sample the result must be:

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("530d24150fef5d9b065909ca"),
    "name" : "name 2",
    "my_array" : [
        {"key" : "date", "value": 9},
        {"key" : "id", "value": 11}
     ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("530d24150fef5d9b065909ca"),
    "name" : "name 3",
    "my_array" : [
        {"key" : "date", "value": 10},
        {"key" : "id", "value": 13},
        {"key" : "name", "value": 'test'},
     ]
}
```

And, I had tried about the follow command line:

```js
db.test.find({"my_array.key": 'id', "my_array.value": {$gt : 10}})
db.test.find({"my_array":{"key": 'id', "value": {$gt : 10}}})
```

Those are all not work...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [$elemMatch](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/) to achieve the same.

Try following query.

```
db.test.find({my_array: {$elemMatch: {key: 'id', value: {$gt: 10}}}})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works. But the result have some empty item, and only show the 'my_array' field without 'name' or others. How to drop those and show all the field.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [**`$elemMatch`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) to find a document that contains both of the elements that match your conditions:

```js
db.test.find(
    {
        "my_array": { "$elemMatch":{ 
            "key": "id", "value": { "$gt" : 10 }
        }}
    },
    {
        "my_array.$": 1
    }
)
```

Keep in mind that this is matching the document and not the array elements. The use of projection here will only get the **first** value.

If you have multiple entries to filter within the array you need to use aggregate:

```js
db.test.aggregate([
    { "$match": {
        "my_array": { "$elemMatch":{ 
            "key": "id", "value": { "$gt" : 10 }
        }}
    }},
    { "$unwind": "$my_array" },
    { "$match": {
        "my_array.key": "id",
        "my_array.value": { "$gt" : 10 }
    }},
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "name": { "$first": "$name" },
        "my_array": { "$push": "$my_array" }
    }}
])
```

Answer (score 1):

Refer this to find ans of your question.
`db.test.find({my_array: {$elemMatch: {key: 'id', value: {$gt: 10}}}})`

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works. But the result have some empty item, and only show the 'my_array' field without 'name' or others. How to drop those and show all the field.